# PHPExcel input has 2 sheets, output only has 1 of them saved

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am having admins update a website by uploading `.xlsx` `.xls` or `.csv` files into an HTML form.  The issue is that the second worksheet, `NORTH`, isn't being saved into the server with the first worksheet, `SOUTH`.

My Code:

```
<?php 
require('./Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');

ini_set('max_execution_time', 800);
ini_set('memory_limit', 200M);  

$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'];

class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter {

    public function __construct($fromColumn, $toColumn) {
        $this->columns = array();
        $toColumn++;
        while ($fromColumn !== $toColumn) {
        $this->columns[] = $fromColumn++;
        }
    }

    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
          // Read columns from 'A' to 'AF'
          if (in_array($column, $this->columns)) {
              return true;
          }
          return false;
      }
}

$filterSubset = new MyReadFilter('A', 'AF'); 

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

$objReader->setReadFilter($filterSubset); 

$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly( array("SOUTH", "NORTH") );

$objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

$objWriter->save('abc.csv');

$files = fopen('abc.csv', 'r'); 
    while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {
    $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
    }
?>
```

What have I done wrong that won't allow my code to save both worksheets? TIA!

Comment: CSV doenst allow worksheets, xls and xlxs do.

Comment: Really? I guess I just figured they did because when you edit them in MS Excel you can open a new one (never tried saving it, I assume it errors). I suppose I'll just save them as two different spreadsheets. Thanks @Stefan

Comment: MS Excel itself only allows you to save a single worksheet when you save as csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CSV file can only hold a single worksheet, so you need to save each worksheet to a separate file

```
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly( array("SOUTH", "NORTH") );
$objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

for ($ws = 0; $ws < $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetCount(); $ws++) {
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');
    $objWriter->setSheetIndex($ws);
    $objWriter->save('abc' .$ws. '.csv');
}
```